# Lists will show null even though assigned in constructor

Tags: c#, list, nullreferenceexception

```
public class Aitken 
{
private readonly List<double> X;
private readonly List<double> Y;

        public Aitken()
        {
            List<double> X = new List<double>() { 0, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0 };
            List<double> Y = new List<double>() { 1.0, 0.6065, 0.4724, 0.3679};
        }

      public void Print()
       { 
          Console.WriteLine(X == null);
          Console.WriteLine(Y == null);
       }
}
```

This is the example of what I'm having problems with. I initiate, say two lists in the constructor. If I check for the null reference exception in the constructor right away, everything is fine. But when an another method calls the lists it throws a null reference exception. Both of them are member variables so I don't quite get why this would happen. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Drop `List<double>` pieces from the constructor. With that you define local variables `X` and `Y` there, instead of assigning values to the instance fields of the same name.

Comment: Run your code in the debugger. Look at `this.X` and at `Aitken.X`.

Answer (score 4):

In the constructor, you are not assigning to the fields of your class, you are creating new local variables and initializing them.

You should remove  `List<double>` and just do:

```
X = new List<double>() { 0, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0 };
Y = new List<double>() { 1.0, 0.6065, 0.4724, 0.3679};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating new lists in the constructor

Change the constructor to this:

```
    public Aitken()
    {
        X = new List<double>() { 0, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0 };
        Y = new List<double>() { 1.0, 0.6065, 0.4724, 0.3679};
    }
```

This will assign the lists to the member variables.

I would recommend you read up on variable scope in C# to understand your problem fully :-)